# Cannot find module 'lightning/flowSupport' from 'force-app/main/default/lwc/lwcomponent/__test__/lwcomponent.test.js'

Tags: visual-workflow, lwc-jest, flowsupport

Getting below error on `import {FlowNavigationNextEvent} from 'lightning/flowSupport';` in jest test file.

Cannot find module 'lightning/flowSupport' from 'force-app/main/default/lwc/lwcomponent/**test**/lwcomponent.test.js'

```
   5 | import lwcomponent from 'c/lwcomponent'
   6 | import {createElement} from 'lwc'
>  7 | import {FlowNavigationNextEvent} from 'lightning/flowSupport';
     | ^
   8 |
   9 | /**
  10 |  *  @description For debugging in webkit console
```

**Version Details:**

```
├── @prettier/plugin-xml@0.12.0
├── @salesforce/eslint-config-lwc@0.11.1
├── @salesforce/eslint-plugin-aura@2.0.0
├── @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest@1.0.1
├── eslint-config-prettier@6.15.0
├── eslint@7.31.0
├── husky@4.3.8
├── lint-staged@10.5.4
├── prettier-plugin-apex@1.10.0
└── prettier@2.3.2

Any idea why flowSupport is not working in jest??
```

Comment: What version is your sfdx-lwc-jest ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Its @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest@1.0.1

Comment: Can you share your whole test case?

Comment: Sure, i have a lwc used in flow for which i am trying to create a jest test flie. But import flowSupport in jest while running test command is throwing error of can’t find module.

Comment: sorry i meant share minimum reproducible code?

Answer (score 3):

The lightning modules need to be mocked as jest doesn't have access to import modules like a lightning web component actually could. lwc-jest provides stubs to some modules that come with lwc-jest. You can see a list of the provided [lightning-stubs](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/tree/master/src/lightning-stubs).

As you can see, there's no `flowSupport`. There's actually an [issue](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/issues/244) created to provide this stub in the repo, but you can always create your own stub so you can test your components.

Below is just copied from the issue above, but is an example of a stub so your LWC will be able to use `new FlowNavigationNextEvent();`

```javascript
export const FlowAttributeChangeEventName = 'lightning__flowattributechange';

export class FlowAttributeChangeEvent extends CustomEvent {
 constructor(attributeName, attributeValue) {
    super(FlowAttributeChangeEventName, {
        composed: true,
        cancelable: true,
        bubbles: true,
        detail: {
            attributeName,
            attributeValue
        }
    });
  }
}

export const FlowNavigationNextEventName = 'lightning__flownextevent';

export class FlowNavigationNextEvent extends CustomEvent {
 constructor(attributeName, attributeValue) {
    super(FlowNavigationNextEventName, {
        composed: true,
        cancelable: true,
        bubbles: true,
        detail: {
            attributeName,
            attributeValue
        }
    });
  }
}
```

You'll then want to map this new stub you created for `flowSupport` to the actual `flowSupport` module in jest which is done through `moduleNameMapper` in the `jest.config.js` file.

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^lightning/flowSupport$':
        '<rootDir>/force-app/main/default/lwc/__tests__/lightning/yourFlowSupportStub'
},
```

In your jest test, you'll then import this module (which'll actual leverage your stub you created above)

```
import { FlowNavigationNextEvent } from "lightning/flowSupport";
```